# Python - how to preserve unsorted list order in dictionary without separate data structures

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list whose elements are arranged using some external business logic, and should not be sorted alphabetically or in any other order.
I also have a dictionary whose keys are the list elements.
This compels me to maintain two different data structures. If I add an element to the list, I have to add the key to the dictionary, and vice versa. It's a duplication of databases. I would like to avoid that.
I am planning to avoid it using tuples in a list L: [(k1, v1), (k2, v2), ...] where k1, k2, etc are in the right order.
Is there a better built-in data structure that will let me address this more elegantly? Efficiency in random access would be preferred. Right now, accessing L[k3] is basically O(n). On the other hand, dict(L) would not preserve order, when I want to print the keys out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`collections.OrderedDict()` dictionary subclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain order. Adding new keys adds them to the 'end' of the order, deleting keys preserves the remaining order.

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

When creating an `OrderedDict()` instance from a list, do feed it `(key, value)` pairs in sequence, to set the initial order. Don't be tempted to pass in a regular dictionary, since such objects don't have a specific order you'll end up creating an instance with that same arbitrary order.